# Can I return the raw XML from SOAP::Lite without turning on debug?

Tags: xml, perl, soap

Debug is a nice feature, but what I'd like is to be able to return the "readable" raw xml from either the request or the response with a method. This way I can print them out in a `note` in my test framework. Can anyone tell me how I might do this?

Comment: the real answer appears to be no.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `outputxml` flag what you're after?

---

From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP%3a%3aLite):

> ```
> outputxml()
> ```
>
> Lets you specify the kind of output from all method calls. If true,
>   all methods will return unprocessed, raw XML code. You can parse it
>   with XML::Parser, SOAP::Deserializer or any other appropriate module.

Comment: well I could hack around this... but I don't really want all calls to output xml I just want an accessor to the xml for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A little late (hah!), but I was looking for the same and in the version of the library we're using I was able to do the following:

```pl
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new()
    # ->uri(...)->proxy(...)->autotype(0)
    ;
my $header = SOAP::Header->name(...);
my $som = $soap->call('method' => $args, $header);
my $serializer = SOAP::Serializer->new;
my $xml = $serializer->serialize($som->dataof('//')); # includes a lot of attributes...
# or
my $xml = $serializer->serialize($som->valueof('//'));
```

This is not *exactly* the same, but might be complete enough for most uses.